# ISA Proxy Server can't pass MSDN websites

Tags: proxy

I can get here, but no one at work using our proxy can seem to get to MSDN.

Our Network Administrator has no clue. He said if I could figure it out, he'd fix it. He thinks it is because the ISA Server is too old to understand Microsoft's newer HTML technology.

Comment: This is not a programming related question and is more adapted to http://serverfault.com Unfortunately because of the bounty cannot vote to move it there.

Comment: Thanks! I posted this over 2 months ago with no responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normally a DNS problem.

If it is just this site, it may be that the address to MSDN is registered incorrectly in a HOSTS file or the internal DNS.

For other possibilities see: http://forums.isaserver.org/m_2002006838/mpage_1/key_/tm.htm#2002006915

Answer (score 0):

Are there any errors in the ISA logs? ISA should be able to handle these websites.

Comment: Our Network Administrator won't release the ISA logs because of security issues. He has installed all of the latest patches available, but I still only get "Error Code 10060: Connection timeout" (not from home on my personal Internet connection, but here at work using the ISA Proxy).